# Definition of a vector valued function using arg length as a parameter

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let a vector-valued function, $r(t)$,$a\leq t\leq b$ represent a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then what does it mean for $r(t)$ to use arc length as a parameter?

It seems like definitions vary by books.

1. $\int_{a}^{t}\mid r'(u)\mid\mathrm{d}u=t$
2. $\mid r'(u)\mid$=1 in which case $\int_{a}^{t}\mid r'(u)\mid\mathrm{d}u=t-a$. So $a$ can be non-zero.

I am wondering which one is correct or if both are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition doesn't work unless $a=0$: the left-hand side evaluates to $0$ when $t=a$, while the right-hand side gives $a$. Are you sure that the books that use this do not take their curves on $(0,b)$ for some $b$?

The second one, however, does work and should be standard.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! In case of 1., a was always $0$.